# Java - how does it load and find the right method

Tags: java, jvm, stack

I am trying to understand how Java selects the right method and how it works internally.

Say I have two functions:

```
public void print(int i) { System.out.println("int: " + i); }
```

and

```
public void print(String s) { System.out.println("String: " + s); }
```

How does Java actually

1. Store all of the accessible classes and methods?
2. Determine which overloaded method is the right one to use?

I know that as I call methods it puts them on the JVM stack but I'm trying to understand what happens just before that.  How is it all stored and loaded internally?

Thanks!

Comment: It's actually the compiler that will decide which method is called here, since *overloads* are a compile-time feature. I don't know the exact format of the metadata for Java classes, but I'm sure you could dig up some documentation if you Bing-ed it.

Comment: @dlev _bing-ed it_??? Hmm, dlev `->` location `->` Redmond, WA. Explains everything.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Or you could just read from his profile that he works at Microsoft.

Comment: Too broad to be answered here.

Answer (score 0):

Answers to such questions better be searched in [JLS(Method Invocation Expressions)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12) paragraph. Rewriting its content here is useless. I've also found a more informal description of the hardest part to understand - [choosing the most specific method.](http://geekexplains.blogspot.ru/2009/06/choosing-most-specific-method-tricky.html)